# How to call a rpc in React?

Tags: reactjs, rpc, react-query

I'm using reactjs but i don't know how to send request (GET or POST) with rpcs.
Also, is there a difference in using react query for this?
I know how to send with REST or GraphQL but But I don't know the difference with rpc !